# twitter bootstrap 3 setting active tab in js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Yeah, so this has been asked about 1000 times, but I tried the answers and none seem to be working for me.

Here are my tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#account" data-toggle="tab">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#security" data-toggle="tab">Security</a></li>
    <li><a href="#recruiting" data-toggle="tab">Recruiting</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note, none are set to active by default. The tab panes:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="account">
        Account
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="security">
        Security
    </div>
    ...more...
</div>
```

In my js, I am doing this per the bootstrap docs:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $('#tab a:first').tab('show');
    });
```

Nothing shows. What I am trying to do is have it default open the first tab, but depending on some data I pass in I would like to call this if needed:

```
$('#tab a:[href="#security"]').tab('show');
```

Comment: Would this not want to be `$('.nav a[href="#security"]').tab('show');`

Comment: @Carl, yeah.. I am particularly challenged today. *facepalm*

Comment: @davidisawesome, HAHA, we all have days like those.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The first problem is here:

```
$('#tab a:first').tab('show')
```

`#tab` makes reference to an `id="tab"`, and you don't have one. Replace `#tab` with `.nav-tabs` or add an ID to your ul:

```
$('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show')
```

Your second problem is that you forgot to remove the `:` next to the `a`:

```
$('.nav-tabs a:[href="#security"]').tab('show')
```

It should be:

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#security"]').tab('show')
```

Comment: thanks, combination of your answer and @Satpal was my problem.

Comment: or subtitute nav-tabs with nav-pills if that's what you happen to be using :)

Answer (score 8):

You have `:` in your selector, Change it to

```
 $('#tab a[href="#security"]').tab('show');
```

instead of

```
 $('#tab a:[href="#security"]').tab('show');
```