# Laravel - Redirect back to tab-pane

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm having a small issue with working with `tab-panes` . Basically i set home as active , then on the other pane i have a `form` to modify the Home . however each time i `modify/refresh` the page - it automatically goes back to home even when i use the url `.../settings#edit-home`

Is there any way to fix that ?

I want it to stay on whichever pane i'm on even when i refresh and when i `submit` the form , it should redirect back to the same page instead of the "home".

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills ">

    <li role="presentation" class="active" href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>

    <li role="presentation" href="#edit-home" data-toggle="tab"><a href="#edit-home">Modify Home</a></li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

 <div class="tab-pane active " id="home">
 ...
 </div>

 <div class="tab-pane" id="edit-home">
 ...
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe my answer is late, but it could help someone. I run into same issues and here is my solution:

In controller redirect to hashed url (I have validation):

```
 return redirect()
    ->to('/users/account#myphotos')
    ->withErrors($v->errors());
```

And with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.hash == '#myphotos') {
        $('li.myprofile').removeClass('active');//remove active class
        $('div#myprofile').removeClass('active');
        $('li.myphotos').addClass('active');
        $('div#myphotos').addClass('in active');
    }
});
```

So just change class and id names and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JQuery to read the hash `window.location.hash` and set the correct tab to active.

So something kind of like `$('.nav-pills a[href="#'+window.location.hash+'"]').tab('show');` should work.  You'll need to wrap that in an if statement so you don't set the tabs to blank so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        $('.nav-pills a[href="#'+window.location.hash+'"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

I partially copied from [twitter bootstrap 3 setting active tab in js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417905/twitter-bootstrap-3-setting-active-tab-in-js-not-working) which is nav-tabs so I'm hoping nav-pills has the same API with twitter bootstrap.