# Setting a different tab pane as active when visiting from other link

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have the below tabs in my page (a.html)

```
<li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#Details" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="#help" data-toggle="tab">Help</a></li>
```

I have another page b.html, where I have a button that links to a.html. When I click on that button  I want the "help" tag in a.html to get active.

I tried something like

```
<a href="a.html#help"></a>
```

Edit 1 : I need Home to be active when I load a.html separately. And I need Help to be active only when i move from *b.html* to *a.html*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [twitter bootstrap 3 setting active tab in js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417905/twitter-bootstrap-3-setting-active-tab-in-js-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the click event of the Tab that you want to display on the load of a.html

I've actually just done this myself.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#help").trigger("click");
});
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a .active class in the target tab pane in the other html 
Example:

```
<div class="tab-pane active"></div>
```